# Sql query to show count(*) of groups while keeping all rows of the group

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4, group-by, eloquent

I have a table similar the following

```
id  user_id     father_id
1   1              1
2   2              1
3   3              2
4   4              2
5   5              2
6   6              3
7   7              4
```

I search for a sql query (prefer Fluent or Eloquent for Laravel 4) to give me the following result:

```
id  user_id     father_id   family_members
3   3              2             3
4   4              2             3
5   5              2             3
1   1              1             2
2   2              1             2
6   6              3             1
7   7              4             1
```

As it can be observed `family_members` is the count of users who have the same `father_id`

```
select id, user_id, father_id, count(*) as family_members from users group by father_id
```

The query above, just keeps the top row of each group, but I want to keep all the other records and not only the first one; then sorting them first according to the `family_members` and then according to `father_id`

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know Fluent, nor Eloquent, nor Laravel 4, but the sql query would be like this.

```
 SELECT yourTable.*, auxTable.family_members  
   FROM yourTable
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT father_id, COUNT(id) as family_members
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY father_id
    )auxTable ON yourTable.father_id = auxTable.father_id
ORDER BY family_members DESC, yourTable.father_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by the following Fluent query based on the answer from segio0983

```
 $users = DB::table('users')
    ->leftjoin(DB::raw('(SELECT  father_id, COUNT(id) as family_members
        FROM users
        GROUP BY father_id) auxTable '),function($join)
        {
            $join->on('users.father_id', '=', 'auxTable.father_id');
        })
    ->orderBy('auxTable.family_members','desc')
    ->orderBy('users.father_id','asc')
    ->select('users.id','users.father_id','auxTable.family_members');
```